# Given a port return the corresponding service (e.g. http, ssh, ...) in Golang

Tags: go, dns, port

I was playing around with the `net` package in go. While I see many useful Lookup* functions, it doesn't seem like any of them return the service used given a port.

For example (this is purely made up):

```
service, err := net.LookUpService(23)
// service is ssh
```

I see this can actually be achieved in node with `dns.lookupService` where the callback provided actually is given a service. Is something similar possible in go ? I found the reverse where given a service and network (e.g. tcp, udp) it returns the port, but I kind of want the opposite. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Any idea what Node's `dns.lookupService` is actually doing? Because what you're describing isn't really a thing - anything can be running on any port and there's no universal way to identify them. Service lookups (e.g. `LookupSRV` in `net.Resolver`) return a port, but AFAIK reverse lookup is not supported for SRV records.

Comment: It seems like they are using the os `getnameinfo` and are able to return a `service` which is then passed to the callback.

Comment: I know that Go might use the same underlying `getnameinfo` C function but I couldn't find out how they are extracting the service from the port number in Node. Would it make more sense if I had the hostname and the port to return the service ?

Comment: Which is odd because `getnameinfo` doesn't take a port. `getservbyport` does, but it's just looking it up from a text file on the system, and it's only supported on *nix systems. What are you trying to achieve with this functionality?

Comment: You could achieve the same functionality by creating a set of constants matching the contents of the services file, which is just taken from IANA port registrations. https://linux.die.net/man/5/services just know that this doesn't mean anything is listening on that port, or if something is, it may or may not be the service that's assigned to that port by IANA.

Comment: It might be what Node does wrapping the `getnameinfo` method because their implementation takes a port as well. I was just trying to mirror their functionality but I was wondering if there was some underlying system level reference that I could use without reinventing the wheel. Thanks for the link btw!

Comment: I might close this question, I feel like it's too generic to allow people to answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Adrian "Because what you're describing isn't really a thing" It absolutely is. Unix systems have a `/etc/services` file that maps port number to service name, as registered by IANA. The libc has functions to request one data when you have another. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservbyname

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes. Read the rest of my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in package `netdb` at https://godoc.org/honnef.co/go/netdb

> Package netdb provides a Go interface for the protoent and servent
> structures as defined in netdb.h
>
> A pure Go implementation is used by parsing /etc/protocols and
> /etc/services

And specifically:

> func GetServByPort
>
> func GetServByPort(port int, protocol *Protoent) *Servent
>
> GetServByPort returns the Servent for a given port number and
> protocol. If the protocol is nil, the first service matching the port
> number is returned.

Comment: Oh nice, I'll play with that right away to see if it works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Just a quick update, this is definitely what I was looking for! looking into the `etc/services` file and extract a mapping port -> service is perfect. It's not currently working as I always get a nil `Servent` but that's definitely helpful! Thank you, I learned something new today!

Comment: Last update, this actually works exactly like I wanted! There seems to be a small bug but I'm about to submit a PR for it. Amazing, thank you again!